# Any way to transfer Store View values to Default Values in Magento?

Tags: magento, default, overwrite

We're a few years and 11,000+ products into our Magento store and we had to shift gears a bit.

Life would be easier if the values (titles, enabled/disabled, descriptions) used in the Store View could overwrite the Default Values without endless hours of copy/pasting.

So, if the Store View Value is different than the Default Value, make that the Default Value. Help appreciated!

Comment: What are you referring to?   Categories or products

Comment: Products. Would like any product value unique in the store view to become the default value.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done directly with SQL, but be sure to set maintenance mode and backup before you start.

```sql
SET @default = 0;
SET @store = 1;
-- put the correct store_id here

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT entity_type_id, attribute_id, @default, entity_id, value FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS local
WHERE store_id = @store
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = local.value;
-- the "ON DUPLICATE..." part works because EAV tables have
-- a unique key for "entity_id, attribute_id, store_id"

DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE store_id = @store;
-- it is safe to delete @store rows because all values
-- have been either copied or updated by now

COMMIT;
```

Repeat the above for all `catalog_product_entity_*` tables.  Then rebuild indexes, you can do that while the site is in maintenance mode with SSH...

```
cd path/to/magento/shell/
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
```

Comment: Thank you! We're going to make some backups and give this a go fairly soon.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a PHP script that goes through the storeview values, copies them to default scope if they are different and then deletes the local value.

You can see the GIST here: https://gist.github.com/janzikmund/a92e0a219af5e362fa1293b52b6b831e .

It is commented to give you the idea. At the bottom the UPDATE and TRUNCATE lines are commented out, so you should be able to first run it without any data modification and then when you are sure uncomment these lines and transform the data.

Of course don't forget to do a backup first!